# sharing authentication within two drupal distributions

Tags: 7, users

I am looking for a module or a way where two different drupal distributions can share the same authentication or user database ? Is there a module that can help with that ?

possibilities-

if user A logged into site-1,  the user should be logged in automatically to site-2.

if thats not possible, if user 1 creates a login on site-1, he should also be able to use the same login credentials on site-2 or vice versa.

Comment: both sites are on the same root domain or on different domains?

Comment: they are on different domains

Comment: if user A logged in to site-1, should the user be logged in automatically to site-2?

Comment: Yes, that would be something i'm hoping for. But if thats not possible, if user 1 creates a login on site-1, he should also be able to use the same login credentials on site-2.

Answer (score 1):

This method comes with a list of caveats, but it's possible to simply [share the users table across multiple installations](http://drupal.org/node/22267) via a table prefix array in settings.php.

> **Example: Sharing Users**
>   This example shows how to share users. The
>   users from a master site prefixed with 'master_' are shared to a slave
>   site prefixed with 'slave1_'.

```
$db_prefix = array(
    "default" => "slave1_", // the prefix for tables that are not shared.
    "users" => "master_",
    "sessions" => "master_",
    "authmap" => "master_",
    "sequences" => "master_",
    "profile_fields" => "master_",
    "profile_values" => "master_",
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibility 1: Try [OAuth](http://drupal.org/project/oauth) module

> [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) is an open protocol to allow secure API authentication in a simple and standard method from desktop and web applications.

Possibility 2: Try [Bakery](http://drupal.org/project/bakery) module

> Bakery provides a "single sign on" feature for Drupal based sites that are on the same second-level domain (i.e. example.com, subsite.example.com, subsite2.example.com). It could also provide support for any other website that implements the same web cookie, xmlrpc, and POST methods.

Also, check other options

[Comparison of Single Sign On (SSO) Modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/182004)

Answer (score 0):

I guess drupal gardens do the same you are asking for.
Basically one of your drupal installation act as drupal open id as server and other as client,kinda login with facebook.
So user first registers to drupal open id server and gets an open id and now user logs in other drupal installation with same id and this drupal server interacts internally to other drupal server for authentication so if you are logged in drupal open id server installation you can direclty logged in to drupal open id client installation, drupal gardens passes your open id as url.

this approach may require time and research.